# Sonata (Admin/User/DoctrineORMAdmin) Bundle: Weird issue when creating user groups

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata

I've managed to setup sonata admin/user/doctrineormadmin bundle with many many problems.

Now it is all running smooth, I can manage my entities, I can add users, assign roles and I could even make user groups. But when I do, say I create a group named "Test Group", then when I open up the users, the script tries to list all groups, so I could assign the user to any of them. But even before that I get the error: `Class Test Group does not exist`!?

This is really weird since there should be no class with the name of the group I just created.. The name is persisted with Doctrine in the DB and no local files should handle it... I don't get it.

Maybe I'm missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else had this problem, I found a solution.

There were 2 errors in a base sonata class, weirdly no one else saw this.. how, I don't know. Anyway, I fixed the errors and sent a pull request on github, hopefuly they will merge it and fix it for everybody :)

https://github.com/ton4y/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.0/Form/ChoiceList/ModelChoiceList.php